# Custom Wordpress Authentication Plugin not working

Tags: php, wordpress, hash, authentication

It's been a while since I used Wordpress but I got requested to look at a custom authentication plugin that does not appear to be working. I just copied and pasted the relevant snippet of code that I can't seem to get to work right. The check password always appears to be incorrect.

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$hash = wp_hash_password('$pass');

$query = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from users where username='$user'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$check = wp_check_password( $pass, $hash)
}
```

$check ALWAYS equals false. Anyone have any idea's? Additionally, won't wp_hash_password make a different hash everytime because it adds salt to it? For example; when I write

`$hash = wp_hash_password('pizza'); echo $hash;`

the hash is always different. So how can

`wp_check_password($pass,$hash)`

work if the hash is always different?

I'd really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `wp-config.php` for [secret key definitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Security_Keys), as they can alter the auth hash by salting it. If they are there, you may have to use [`wp_salt`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_salt) to salt your password before comparing it against the database.

Edit:
Secret keys also exist in the options table in the database. They can be applied from either `wp-config.php` or the database.  If your site has been moved or edited in the past, you may have to check both places to be sure as to whether WordPress is salting passwords.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know how can I pass the salt to the hash function?

Comment: Could you just use `wp_check_password` to compare the plain text password against the hash in the database, without hashing the password yourself?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that but unfortunately, it always comes back as false

Comment: Then, either the original salt has changed or it has been deleted.  Either way, the best approach, in my opinion, would be to create a new secret key and re-encrypt / reset all the passwords using it. You can do this as a admin/super-admin by going to the user's profile and entering in the new password.